# How to get HDOP, PDOP, Satellite Availability while fetching user location from iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation, cllocationcoordinate2d

I am working on an `iOS` application where along with the coordinate I need to send `HDOP`, `PDOP` & Satellite Availability to the server.

**I don't understand how do I get this `HDOP`, `PDOP` & Satellite Availability from iPhone and iPad?**

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how do I get this HDOP, PDOP & Satellite Availability from iPhone and iPad?

Sadly the answer is "you don't". iOS doesn't expose any of that information. To get information like that you'd need to use an external GPS receiver, and yet again iOS comes in the way and makes that very tricky because it's extremely limited to which Bluetooth devices you can connect to, and don't provide an out of the box way to connect to any generic serial-over-Bluetooth device (so make sure you research before you buy).

Comment: Yeah we have one external GPS, which we have connected and now we are getting those values.

Answer (score -2):

You can get HDOP from below function:

```
public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let hdop: Double = locations!.horizontalAccuracy / 5.0
    //5.0 is horizontal accuracy ratio
  }
```

Comment: No this is _not_ what HDOP is. HDOP is a measure of how good the satellite constellation is for obtaining horizontal positions. It says nothing about the actual accuracy. It's sort of saying "the car is going fast because it's a good road without knowing anything about the car or the driver".
Typically the accuracy is derived from the residuals that are produced during the GPS Fix calculation.